# Create a Snapshot of current android device state and save it for later restore

Tags: android, operating-system, android-emulator, android-os-handler

I would like to take a snapshot of current device state (including state of apps). Just like we do for emulator. For reference check this link.
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#snapshots

I would like to know if it is possible for a real android device. I think the OS do it internally when a new OS update is installed on the device.

I will use this snapshot with appium.

Comment: TWRP and CWM can backup and restore partitions

Comment: What options do I have for a non rooted device

Comment: Technically TWRP and CMW only require unlocked bootloader, but if you only have stock ROM with locked bootloader, I'd guess no, backing up *entire* state could be security risk after all.